# How to open and read from an external text file in odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I want to open a .txt file using python in odoo and read its contents. Where should I place this .txt file for it to be opened.

What I tried,

I kept the file in the same directory as models.py and in models.py wrote the code to open the file,

```
try:
    logFile = open('log.txt', 'r')
```

but this file is not opened. Please help, where should I keep log.txt for it to be located, or can I set any path for models.py to understand where log.txt is?

Answer (score 2):

I just found the solution, I set the absolute path to where the .txt file is found.

```
import os

path = os.path.expanduser('<absolute path to .txt file>')
logFile = open(path, 'r')
```

this worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is Python Code may be help you:

```
with open("log.txt") as file:   # Use file to refer to the file object
    data = file.read()
    do something with data
    print data
```

File handling in Python See this link : http://pymbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/file.html

Comment: I tried your code, it doesn't work either. There's no problem in the code, it's about where to place the file in odoo, for models.py to recognize it. Or at least to give a path to help models.py recognize where the .txt file is